# Set Groovy Version within Jenkins Pipeline Template

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Our devs have written the following templates and the team have found a bug with Jenkins Groovy Core 2.4.21 (the team completed an upgrade from Jenkins 2.303.1 Groovy Core 2.4.12 to Jenkins 2.387.1 Groovy Core 2.4.21 within the Sandbox environment)

Im just investigate a quick and easy way to update Groovy without delaying the production upgrade

Example Jenkins Template

```
#!groovy
package pipelines.templates

pipeline {
    agent { label("maven-test-agent") }
    stages {
        stage("Setup workspace") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def workspace = load "src/modules/Workspace.groovy"
                    workspace.setup("resources/definitions/ecsDeployTemplate.yaml", false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Create ECS Build Deploy job") {
            steps {
                script {
                    log.heading("Create ECS Build Deploy job")
                    def jenkins = load "src/modules/Jenkins.groovy"
                    jenkins.createPipeline()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                def postAction = load "src/modules/PostAction.groovy"
                postAction.perform(false, true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please correct me if I’m wrong but I need to rewrite these templates and move away from using pipeline script steps, if I set the following “withGroovy” (see below) this seems to be ignored and still triggers Jenkins core groovy version 2.4.21

```
pipeline {
    agent { label("maven-test-image") }
    tools {
        groovy 'Groovy-2.5.1'
    }
}
```

or

```
post {
    always {
        script {
            withGroovy(tool:'Groovy-2.5.1'){
                def postAction = load "src/modules/PostAction.groovy"
                data.athena.metadata["updated"] = false
                postAction.perform(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I should be completely rewriting the way the scripts are triggered within a pipeline job as an example

```
stage ('Example') {
    steps {
        withGroovy(tool:'Groovy-2.5.1') {
            sh 'groovy deploy.groovy'
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice or tips would be much appreciated

References
[https://community.jenkins.io/t/upgrade-groovy-jenkins-plugin/6892](https://stackoverflow.com)
[https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-53372](https://stackoverflow.com)
[https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/groovy/#groovy](https://stackoverflow.com)